# Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: initializeApp

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite

I am trying to implement firebase authentication in my react + vite app.

firebase.jsx

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA4P225SDzY5xUQgb3o1BQUfnXA5GGSbO4",
  authDomain: "healthask-91168.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "healthask-91168",
  storageBucket: "healthask-91168.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "999687978236",
  appId: "1:999687978236:web:5eb5a1d677b590ed7f6b79",
};
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore();
```

I'm trying to importing db in one of my component using

`import { db } from "../../firebase";`

Similarly When I'm trying to import any of firebase libraries eg: doc,getDoc etc getting similar error corresponding to that library.

OAuth.jsx -> This is where I want to import firebase libraries

```
// import React from "react";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// import { doc, getDoc, serverTimestamp, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase";

export const OAuth = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  async function HandelGoogleLogin() {
    // try {
    //   const auth = getAuth();
    //   const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    //   const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
    //   const user = userCredential.user;

    //   const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    //   const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    //   if (!docSnap.exists()) {
    //     await setDoc(docRef, {
    //       name: user.displayName,
    //       email: user.email,
    //       timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    //     });
    //   }
    //   navigate("/");
    // } catch (error) {
    //   toast("Something went wrong!");
    // }
  }

  return (
    <button
      onClick={HandelGoogleLogin}
      type="button"
      className="mt-1 w-full flex justify-center items-center py-2 px-4 border border-gray-500 rounded-sm shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-black-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500"
    >
      <FcGoogle className="text-xl mr-2 " />
      <p className="text-[0.9rem]">Continue with Google</p>
    </button>
  );
};
```

This is the output of `npm list`

```
├── @emotion/react@11.11.1
├── @emotion/styled@11.11.0
├── @mui/material@5.14.2
├── @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
├── @tinymce/tinymce-react@4.3.0
├── @types/react-dom@18.2.7
├── @types/react@18.2.16
├── @vitejs/plugin-react-swc@3.3.2
├── autoprefixer@10.4.14
├── eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.6.0
├── eslint-plugin-react-refresh@0.4.3
├── eslint-plugin-react@7.33.0
├── eslint@8.45.0
├── firebase-tools@12.4.5
├── firebase@10.1.0
├── postcss@8.4.27
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-icons@4.10.1
├── react-redux@8.1.1
├── react-router-dom@6.14.2
├── react-tag-autocomplete@7.0.0
├── react-tag-input@6.8.1
├── react-toastify@9.1.3
├── react@18.2.0
├── redux@4.2.1
├── tailwindcss@3.3.3
└── vite@4.4.7
```

Thanks any kinda support will be so helpful :)